# How to resolve binding of IMethod in JDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to find the overriden methods without using AST parser in JDT. When I compare methods' signatures from Class file and K-Source file (ICompilationUnit) they appear to be different. Problem of the source file is that, its binding is not resolved, it gives `QString` instead of `java.lang.string`. Does anyone know how to resolve these bindings for source file without dealing with AST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
Signature.toString("QString")
```

will to the job.

Comment: For posterity: With input `"QString"` `Signature.toString()` can only get you the `String` part, not the fully qualified named. Going from unresolved `"QString"` to `java.lang.String` requires resolving, as Ayush correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can only resolve bindings once the AST is constructed. Alternatively, if you have a binding key cached somewhere you can obtain the binding, but again the binding key will have been obtained from the binding itself. So, at some point you will have to resolve bindings.